# Getting "Invalid Key Character" With generated PHP string on Json Curl

Tags: php, json, curl

So, i'm trying to communicate with a curl for a project using php, and send data from my database with the POST method.

but i'm getting the "Invalid Key Character" error, and i really don't know what else to do to fix this...

The code:

```
<?php
require_once('autoload.php');
require_once('vendor/autoload.php');

$conexao = new Conexao();

$produtos = $conexao->select('produto', '*', 'LIMIT 1');

foreach ($produtos as $produto) {
    try {
        $curl = curl_init();

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "url");
        $headers = array();
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/json";
        $headers[] = "X-Api-Key: key";
        $headers[] = "X-App-Key: key";
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);

        $status = 1;

        if ($produto['status'] == 1){ 
            $status = 0;
        }

        $valores = '
        {
            "product":{
                "name":"'. trim($produto['descricao']) .'",
                "sku":"'. trim($produto['cod_est']) .'",
                "description":"'. trim($produto['obs']) .'",
                "price":'. $produto['valor_vend'] .',
                "saleprice":'. $produto['vl_promo'] .',
                "categories": [
                    "'. trim($produto['ender3']) .'"
                ],
                "properties": [],
                "related_products": [],
                "special_options": [],
                "slug":"'. str_replace(' ', '-', trim($produto['descricao'])) .'",
                "excerpt":"'. trim($produto['descricao']) .'",
                "factory_price":'. $produto['ult_custo'] .',
                "installments": 1,
                "shippable":0,
                "fixed_quantity": 999,
                "gtin_code":"'. trim($produto['cod_fabr']) .'",
                "ncm_code":"'. trim($produto['cod_ncm']). '",
                "track_stock": 0,
                "enabled":' . $status . ',
                "video": "",
                "weight":"' . $produto['peso_brut']. '",
                "height": "' . $produto['espessura'] . '",
                "width": "' . $produto['largura'] . '",
                "depth": "' . $produto['compriment'] . '",
                "meta": "",
                "seo_title": "",
                "seo_description":"'. trim($produto['descricao']) . '",
                "seo_keywords":"'. str_replace(' ',',',strtolower(trim($produto['descricao']))) .'"
            }
        }';

        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $valores);

        $response = curl_exec($curl);
        curl_close($curl);

        print_r($response);
    }

    catch (Exception $e){
        echo 'Ocorreu um Erro: ' . $e;
    }

}
```

The error:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8 Content-Length: 263 Connection: keep-alive Cache-Control: max-age=1, public Date: Wed, 27 Dec 2017 19:09:30 GMT Expires: Wed, 27 Dec 2017 19:09:31 GMT Server: Apache Vary: Accept-Encoding X-Cache: Miss from cloudfront Via: 1.1 f2e2a7eca4778c8776461616fad77017.cloudfront.net (CloudFront) X-Amz-Cf-Id: urR4k92zkT2PCfimpCNAf5-uBmUi46nvHM6J-aWVZ8OxDYZUPteEWg== Disallowed Key Characters. "\r\n\t\t{\r\n\t\t\t\"product\":{\r\n\t\t\t\t\"name\":\"PH_CAMISA_GOLA_V_BR_12\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\"sku\":\"2129246\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\"description\":\"\",\r\n\t\t\t\t\"price\":49_000,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"saleprice\":0_000,\r\n\t\t\t\t\"categories\":_"
```

if i copy the generated json and paste to JSONLint, it shows that the json is valid...

Any Tips on how to solve this?

Comment: Don't build your JSON with string concatenation, use `json_encode()` and it will automatically handle any necessary escaping for you.

Comment: The error shows the string has formatting ('\r', '\t', '\n', etc)

Comment: @devlincarnate Is there a way to clean the formatting from the string automatically?

Comment: Yes, let `json_encode()` handle it for you.

Comment: json_encode() just adds a bunch of `\ `, and the error stills occurring...

Disallowed Key Characters. "\"\\r\\n\\t\\t{\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\\"product\\

Answer (score 1):

You just ***don't build JSON by hand*** in PHP.

You first build your data structure and **THEN** you [`json_encode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) the whole thing...

```
$valores = [
    "product" => [
        "name" => trim($produto['descricao']),
        "sku" => trim($produto['cod_est']),
        "description" => trim($produto['obs']),
        "price" => $produto['valor_vend'],
        "saleprice" => $produto['vl_promo'],
        "categories" => [
            trim($produto['ender3']) // I'm not so sure here...
        ],
        "properties" => [],
        ...
        ...
        ...
    ]
];
// $valores is an array containing your data.

$encoded = json_encode($valores);
// $encoded is a string containing encoded JSON.
```

`json_encode()` handles everything for you *(escaping, etc.)*. It also has some options - for that [see the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

Comment: I remade the code creating objects and letting the json_encode convert it, but i'm still getting the same errors...

Comment: Can you provide the exact final JSON you're trying to POST?

Comment: `{"product":{"name":"PH CAMISA GOLA V BR 12","sku":"2129246","description":"","price":"49.000","saleprice":"0.000","categories":"[]","properties":"[]","related_products":"[]","special_potions":"[]","slug":"ph-camisa-gola-v-br-12","excerpt":"PH CAMISA GOLA V BR 12","factory_price":"22.3100","installments":1,"shippable":0,"fixed_quantity":999,"gtin_code":"","ncm_code":"61099000","track_stock":0,"enabled":1,"video":"","weight":"0.001","height":"0.000","width":"0.000","depth":"0.00","meta":"","seo_title":"","seo_description":"PH CAMISA GOLA V BR 12","seo_keywords":"ph,camisa,gola,v,br,12"}}`